# RODBC: can't specify schema with ALTER TABLE command

Tags: sql, r, database-schema, rodbc

I can specify schema with CREATE TABLE or DROP TABLE:

```
sqlQuery(odbcConnect("Hive"), "DROP TABLE schema.table;")
```

but not with ALTER TABLE:

```
sqlQuery(odbcConnect("Hive"), "ALTER TABLE schema.table RENAME TO schema.new_table;")
```

Error message: ...mismatched input 'RENAME' expecting KW_EXCHANGE near 'table' in alter exchange partition

This didn't work either:

```
sqlQuery(odbcConnect("Hive"), "USE schema; ALTER TABLE table RENAME TO new_table;")
```

Error message: ...missing EOF at ';' near 'schema'

P.S. In the end, I worked around this problem using INSERT INTO TABLE. I'd still like to know the answer to the original question, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If possible, you might try upgrading to at least Hive 0.14.0.

The issue with Hive not handling a schema in ALTER TABLE schema.table statements was resolved in Hive 0.14.0  See the following JIRA on this issue:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-9180

If you can upgrade, the original "ALTER TABLE schema.table" command will work.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @BarbaraLaird: "Use a newer version, here's why" seems like a perfectly legitimate answer: it allows direct resolution and explains the necessity. "What version are you using?" would be a comment, though.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem while trying to add new partition. But then I issued 2 statements : "**use schema_name;**" and "**alter table table_name(without schema_name) add partition...**" and everything went OK.
Seems that ALTER statement doesn't support schema name in Hive.
Try to exexute those 2 last statements separetely:
"**USE schema;**" and then
"**ALTER TABLE table RENAME TO new_table;**"
I don't know how to write it in java,but it's quite similar what we have in Oracle database:
when you try to  "**execute immediate 'alter ...smth; alter... smth_else;'**" as a one statement it will fail. But if you separate them like this "**begin execute immediate 'alter ..smth;'; execute immediate 'alter ..smth_else'; end;**" , do it in one transaction and it will succeed.

Comment: I'm not sure how to apply the method you're suggesting in Hive.

Comment: This worked for me! Its a better answer than saying to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

The above solution is worked for me. But it is very weird , that it is working this way.

Seems there is a bug in the hive code, which is stopping this.

I have done the following things in series.

1. Change to the target schema where your can find the table
2. Use   dbname  (`mktg_dd is the name of our DB`)
3. Run the same query

Here's the SQL:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD IF NOT EXISTS PARTITION (viewdate='2014-08-01') location 'path/to data';
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: What does "mktg_dd" do?

Answer (score 0):

If you have table `datbasename.tablename` you will have to execute `stmt.execute("USE databasename");` first.